# problems when running catkin_create_pkg

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to install ROS, and getting to know the environment by following the well written online tutorials.

First I did a complete new ROS install on my Ubuntu 12.04, by following the install instructions here:
wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu

After this I dug right into the tutorials wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials

But on the 3. tutorial, wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage, I am currently stuck, since I get an error when running catkin_create_pkg. It output this to my shell:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/catkin_create_pkg", line 4, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2819, in <module>
parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)
```

I have already tried different things, like reinstalling the whole ROS, tryign to reinstall the python-catkin-pkg, and bunch of other things. Tried to follow the tutorials from scratch several times, to ensure I wasnt missing something.
Read some forums, and can already give some details about the installation:

```
python -c 'import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)'
```

gives

```
/usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
```

Anyone got any clue of how I can fix this error, or maybe where to look? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148776/problems-when-running-catkin_create_pkg/) by [jesperhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/14371/jesperhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-04**:
The /usr/local/... path is somewhat suspicious. For me catkin resides in /usr/bin. Do you have an older manual catkin install from somewhere?

**Comment by [jesperhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/14371/jesperhn/) on 2014-04-07**:
Had ROS groovy installed last year on this machine, maybe that could cause it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed it! Somehow an "EASY-INSTALL-SCRIPT" had put a catkin_create_pkg under /usr/local/bin which was messing with the actual catkin_create_pkg script.
Removed the wrong script (which btw had no actual content), and it worked perfect afterwards!

---

Originally posted by [jesperhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/14371/jesperhn/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0